# Separate maven test project that runs against two other projects

Tags: maven

I have a project that has divided into two projects.  The original project, let's call it *Project-java6*, and a new project, let's call it *Project-java8*.  I need to release both artifacts, one for Java 6/7 users and one for Java 8 users.

The two projects are "identical", in that *Project-java6* was simply copied to *Project-java8* and the code in *Project-java8* modernized (as expected, with Java 8 constructs).  As it stands, both projects have identical unit tests.  The "API" of *Project-java6* and *Project-java8* are identical, so I would like to separate out the unit tests so I'm not constantly updating the same code in two places (that already happens enough with the two projects).

So, I would like something like the following structure:

`Project-java6
Project-java8
Tests`

Where *Tests* is an "independent" maven project.  My challenge (and thus this question) is: how to I get *Tests* to run against both *Project-java6* and *Project-java8*?  Meaning, when the *parent* pom is built, all three projects are built, and the tests are run against *Project-java6* and *Project-java8* respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help you...

You can create an abstract test in the tests module, where you will write the main tests cases. This test will use the interface defined in the first module in the test.

Then, in each module Project-java6 and Project-java8, you create a test that extends the abstract test and call the test methods defined in the tests module.

Regarding Maven :

In the tests module, you will have to indicate to Maven that he has to create a jar of the tests package:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Then, in each implementing module, you will have to indicate that you have a dependency to this test-jar library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>${pom.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I just read this answear in another post, and it seems to be good for you..

Let me know if all is clear...

Comment: It is clear, but it also entails quite a bit of artifice to accomplish the goal.  Including possibly many "tests" in the java6 and java8 modules that extend the abstract tests defined in the tests module.  In ant this would be trivial; maybe I should just do it in ant and invoke it from maven.